# python diffusion solver matrix creation

Tags: python

I have the following code but I keep getting an error in line 46 of my code, TypeError: Cannot interpret '20' as a data type. I have tried multiple methods including doubling up on parenthesis or just typing the number in but to no avail. I cant figure out what I am doing wrong in order to get this. can anyone help me? additionally I have a large portion of code commented out because I need to go back and grab data from a `txt` file or and eventually bring it into the code but in order to fully test my equations I thought it would be easier to just define them in the code and pull the data in later. If you have any advice on how to bring data in from a `txt` file it would also be greatly appreciated.

below is the code.

```
import os
import numpy as np

# import data into variables for use

# nx=[]
# ny=[]
# dx=[]
# dy=[]
# boundcond=[]
# diffcoeff=[]
# with open("diffsolverin.txt","r") as f:
#    content =f.readlines()
#    for x in content:
#        row = x.split()
#        nx.append(int(row[0]))
#        ny.append(int(row[1]))
#        dx.append(float(row[2]))
#        dy.append(float(row[3]))
#        boundcond.append(float(row[4]))
#        diffcoeff.append(float(row[5]))
# sourceterm.append(float(row[6]))


# print(nx, ny, dx, dy, boundcond, diffcoeff)
# n=nx*ny
# create matrix
# a = np.zeros(n,n)
# print ("a")

dx = 0.2
dy = 0.2
nx = 20
ny = 20
boundcond = 0
diffcoeff = 1
sourceterm = 1
flow = 1

# determine boundary condition
# if diffcoeff=0
# put in boundary conditions for this solver will be the same

# if diffcoeff=1
# put in boundary conditions solver will be the same
u = [1] * nx
matrix = np.zeros(nx, ny)
for i in range(2, nx - 1):
    j = i
    alphaplusx = dx * dy * diffcoeff / (dx ** 2)
    alphaminusx = dx * dy * diffcoeff / (dx ** 2)
    alphaplusy = dx * dy * diffcoeff / (dy ** 2)
    alphaminusy = dx * dy * diffcoeff / (dy ** 2)

    matrix[i, i] = -(alphaplusx + alphaminusx) - (alphaplusy + alphaminusy)
    matrix[i - 1, i] = alphaminusx
    matrix[i + 1, i] = alphaplusx
    matrix[i, i - 1] = alphaminusy
    matrix[i, i + 1] = alphaplusy
    ans[i] = (matrix[i, i] + matrix[i - 1, i] + matrix[i + 1, i] + matrix[i, i - 1] + matrix[i, i + 1]) * u(i)
end
print(matrix)
```

Comment: And which one is *line 46*?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a zero-filled matrix of the size `(nx, ny)`, you'll need to pass the matrix size as a tuple:

```
matrix = np.zeros((nx,ny))
```

(instead of `matrix = np.zeros(nx,ny)`).

As it is, Numpy is trying to interpret the value of `ny` as a type code, which doesn't fly.